# Simulating -walletnotify option in Electrum

Tags: electrum

When run in daemon mode, bitcoind accepts a parameter [`-walletnotify=<cmd>`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin) which runs `<cmd>` whenever a wallet transaction changes due to sending/receiving.

Is there a similar feature in Electrum?  If not, how can it be simulated?

The [`watch_wallet`](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/bb7b0884e31f5c7d1a4f93cf63c65401c7f496fd/scripts/watch_address) script seems to do something similar but only works on individual addresses, not whole wallets.  In addition, it only prints a message.

Answer (score 0):

An old question - by the time I saw it - but the Electrum daemon - assuming it is running on Linux of some type must be polled from an external source with software or a cron job.

see [Checking/polling a balance of an address in Electrum via the command line/RPC](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51499/checking-polling-a-balance-of-an-address-in-electrum-via-the-command-line-rpc/58992#58992)